# Finding LocalHost Files

Tags: localhost

I was wondering how I can find localhost files, the laptop I currently use has website blocks, opening localhost files whenever i try to open certain sites or load images from them.  I was wondering if there's a way to find these localhost files so I can circumvent them?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please explain in details what you mean by localhost files? If you have local server running, you can always access it at ```http://127.0.0.1:[port]``` where port is the port the server is listening on

Answer (score 0):

If its localhost, you shouldnt have that much trouble finding them after all localhost is just a reference to your machine so you can just search them using any file explorer like the default one on windows :)
127.0.0.1 refers to your machine so if you have a minecraft server for example on your computer and type 127.0.0.1:4400(i dont remember the standart port for it) it would be a reference to said machine
If you have a xampp server typing your private ipv4 should also link you to localhost

**localhost is just a naming convention defined in RFC 791(correct me if im wrong to refer to the machine you are using**